# Server2019 cannot remove windows features (was a dc)

Tags: windows

i have a 2019 server that was configured as a adfs primary, running ad sync and was also a domain controller. My objective was to remove the server and replace all services on a new VM.

I have managed to move sync across, and removed off the old server, i have also dc promo'd it down to a member server.

The issue i now have is when i try to REMOVE features from the machine i get an error

Failed to remove service ASSEMBLY_MISSING 0x80004005.

The only language pack running is English.

the cbd logs provided below point to a KB4561608.

I have tried to find this on windows catalogue but couldnt, however i did find a win10 update version of it, so iextracted it and installed the cab, but the problem still exists.

i have done a sfc and a dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth both have not resolved the issue

The upshot is all i really want to do is remove the node from the adfs farm, but it looks like the only way of doing this is by uninstalling the feature

There is no other 3rd party AV etc. in play here and i have also moved the member server to a OU that has no GPO inheritance (clutching at straws now !)

Does anyone have any ideas on what i can try next ?

2023-07-05 21:21:30, Error                 CSI    00000009 (F) STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING #7915# from CCSDirectTransaction::OperateEnding at index 0 of 1 operations, disposition 2[gle=0xd015000c]
2023-07-05 21:21:30, Error                 CSI    0000000a (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING) #7757# from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction::ICSITransaction_PinDeployment(Flags = 0, a = 7bab8e317a46eb3430fc83f7ea35efff, version 10.0.17763.1131, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, cb = (null), s = (null), rid = 'Package_3162_for_KB4561608~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.9.4561608-5303_neutral', rah = (null), manpath = (null), catpath = (null), ed = 0, disp = 0)[gle=0x80073701]

2023-07-05 21:20:51, Error                 CSI    00000008@2023/7/5:19:20:51.193 (F) onecore\base\wcp\componentstore\csd_locking.cpp(95): Error STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING originated in function CCSDirectTransaction::LockComponent expression: (null)
[gle=0x80004005]

2023-07-05 21:21:30, Info                  CBS    Failed to pin deployment while resolving Update: Package_3162_for_KB4561608~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.9.4561608-5303_neutral from file: (null) [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
2023-07-05 21:21:30, Info                  CBS    Failed to bulk stage deployment manifest and pin deployment for package:Microsoft-Windows-IdentityServer-STS-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~10.0.17763.1 [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
2023-07-05 21:21:30, Info                  CBS    CommitPackagesState: Started persisting state of packages
2023-07-05 21:21:30, Info                  CBS    CommitPackagesState: Completed persisting state of packages
2023-07-05 21:21:30, Info                  CSI    0000000b@2023/7/5:19:21:30.233 CSI Transaction @0x234b9215350 destroyed
2023-07-05 21:21:30, Info                  CBS    Perf: Resolve chain complete.
2023-07-05 21:21:30, Info                  CBS    Failed to resolve execution chain. [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
2023-07-05 21:21:30, Error                 CBS    Failed to process single phase execution. [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
2023-07-05 21:21:30, Info                  CBS    WER: Generating failure report for package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17763.1, status: 0x80073701, failure source: Resolve, start state: Installed, target state: Installed, client id: DISM Package Manager Provider
2023-07-05 21:21:30, Info                  CBS    Not able to query DisableWerReporting flag.  Assuming not set... [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]